# Open new page on click of button in react

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I want to open `FormStatus` in a new page when I click a button in `Form` page.
Below is my code.

App.js:

```
import Form from "./components/Form";
import FormStatus from "./components/FormStatus";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <Route path="/" component={Form}/>
        <Route exact path="/form-status" component={FormStatus}/>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Form.js

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Form = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Form Page</h1>
            <Link to="/form-status"><button>click</button></Link>
        </div>
    );
}
export default Form;
```

FormStatus.js:

```
import React, {Component} from "react";

class FormStatus extends Component {
    render(){
        return(
            <h1>Form Status Page</h1>
        )
    }
}
export default FormStatus;
```

when I click on the button on `Form` component, my url changes to `http://localhost:3000/form-status`,
but instead of opening a new page, my `FormStatus` component comes below `Form` component.

I want `FormStatus` to open new a page and only shows contents of my `FormStatus` component and not contents of `Form` component

Comment: Import Switch from react-router-dom and wrap your routes with it. This way, only the first match will be shown. See more at: https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Switch

Comment: @pratteekshaurya did you try `<Link to="/form-status" target="_blank"><button>click</button></Link>` ?

Comment: @MariFaleiros A new page opens, but I can still see the contents of both Form and FormStatus on this new page

Comment: @usafder I can still see the contents of both Form and FormStatus in the new page

Comment: @pratteekshaurya then try to put 'exact' in your first route

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, to make this work, you need to change two things in your current code.

1. Use the [`Switch`](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Switch) from the `react-router-dom` and wrap your routes within it.
2. Make your home page (`/`) route `exact` instead of the `/form-status` route, because the `/form-status` route also includes the leading slash (`/`). So since both of them will match the expected route it will render them together.

So your code should be something like this in the `App.js`:

```js
import React from "react";
import Form from "./components/Form";
import FormStatus from "./components/FormStatus";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <div className="App">
          <Route exact path="/" component={Form} />
          <Route path="/form-status" component={FormStatus} />
        </div>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

**Working Demo:**

[image: CodeSandbox]